# Typescript React component type inference

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics, monorepo, tslint

I am having some issue finding a way to achieve what I need to do with TS in a React monorepo.
The structure is kind of classic:

```
...repo related stuff
packages /
    package-a
    package-b
    package-c
   ...other packages
```

where:

- `package-a` is a collection of base react component which are used throughout the whole repo. It has no dependencies over the other two packages (of course because of circular dependency).
- `package-b` has a different sets of components which are linked to some specific external libraries. It has a dependency over `package-a`.
- `package-c` uses components from both `package-a` and `package-b`. Depends on both `a` and `b` packages.

What I am trying to achieve is:

- in `package-a` I have a component with a `linkComponent` prop. This prop is another component which has some specific props. The thing is this component can have a type defined in `package-a` or in `package-b` depending to the component it is passed as prop.

This is the component (with less props obviously):

```
import {FC} from "react";
import type {IBaseLinkProps} from 'package-a';
import {BaseLink} from 'package-a';

interface IBreadcrumbsProps<P extends IBaseLinkProps> {
    linkComponent?: FC<P>;
}

function Breadcrumbs<P extends IBaseLinkProps>({
     linkComponent: LinkComponent = BaseLink
}: IBreadcrumbsProps<P>) {
    return (
        <LinkComponent to={'/path1'}>{'path1'}</LinkComponent>
    );
}

export type {IBreadcrumbsProps};
export {Breadcrumbs};
```

This is the BaseLink in `package-a`:

```
import type {FC, ReactNode} from "react";

interface IBaseLinkProps {
    to: string;
    children: ReactNode;
}

const BaseLink: FC<IBaseLinkProps> = ({children, to}) => (
    <a href={to}>{children}</a>
);

export type {IBaseLinkProps};
export {BaseLink};
```

and this is the link in `package-b`:

```
import type {FC} from "react";
import type {IBaseLinkProps} from 'package-a'

interface IExtendedLinkProps extends Omit<IBaseLinkProps, 'to'> {
    to: {
        pathname: string;
    };
}

const ExtendedLink: FC<IExtendedLinkProps> = ({children, to}) => (
    <a href={to.pathname}>{children}</a>
);

export type {IExtendedLinkProps};
export {ExtendedLink};
```

Now the thing is I need to use this component with both `IBaseLinkProps` and `IExtendedLinkProps` without the possibility to define it in the `Breadcrumbs` component in `package-a` because of circular dependency with `package-b`.

Is there a way to achieve this without getting the error:

```
TS2322: Type  FC<IBaseLinkProps>  is not assignable to type  FC<T> 
Types of property  propTypes  are incompatible.
Type  WeakValidationMap<IBaseLinkProps> | undefined  is not assignable to type  WeakValidationMap<T> | undefined 
Type  WeakValidationMap<IBaseLinkProps>  is not assignable to type  WeakValidationMap<T>
```

or:

```
TS2322: Type  { children: ReactNode; to: string; }  is not assignable to type  T 
 { children: ReactNode; to: string; }  is assignable to the constraint of type  T , but  T  could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint  IBaseLinkProps
```

The closest working solution I found is something like:

```
<Breadcrumbs<IExtendedLinkProps> linkComponent={Link}/>
```

where the linkComponent in the props is defined as: `linkComponent?: FC<T>;` and destructured in the props as: `linkElement: LinkElement = Link`.

But it gives:

```
TS2344: Type  IExtendedLinkProps  does not satisfy the constraint  IBaseLinkProps 
Types of property  to  are incompatible.
Type  {to: {pathname: string}}  is not assignable to type  string
```

---

**Update#1**

My ExtendedLink component must extend the BaseLink and the RouterLinkProps which comes from react-router:

```
interface INavLinkProps
    extends Omit<IBaseLinkProps, 'to'>,
        Omit<RouterLinkProps, 'to'> {
    children: ReactNode;
    to: IDestToken;
}

const Link: FC<INavLinkProps> = ({children, to}) => {
    const {getPathTo} = useNavigation();

    const path = useMemo(() => getPathTo(to), [getPathTo, to]);

    if (!path) {
        throw new Error(`Could not find path for destination: ${to.KEY}`);
    }

    return (
        <RouterLink to={path}>
            {children}
        </RouterLink>
    )
}
```

so it cannot have the to to be a string because it would mean to add additional type checking also in other places.
Furthermore if I try I receive (consider that IDestToken is an object similar to the one I originally posted):
[TSError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1X01.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue here is that `IExtendedLinkProps.to` ({ pathname: string }) is not compatible with `IBaseLinkProps.to` (string)

Which is why you cannot use `Breadcrumbs` with  `ExtendedLink`

Your breadcrumbs render method:

```
        <LinkComponent to={'/path1'}>{'path1'}</LinkComponent>
```

There would obviously be an issue if you used `ExtendedLink` as it expect an object and not a string

One way to make it compatible would be to make `ExtendedLink` accept both string and object

```
interface IExtendedLinkProps extends Omit<IBaseLinkProps, 'to'> {
    to: string | {
        pathname: string;
    };
}

const ExtendedLink: FC<IExtendedLinkProps> = ({children, to}) => (
    <a href={typeof to === 'string' ? to : to.pathname}>{children}</a>
);
```

Comment: Hi @shantr, thanks for your reply. I tried your solution but the "ExtendedLink" has some additional logic so it doesn't work. I updated the question to show you